# How to solve sudden error 500 in Power BI Dataflow

Tags: powerbi

Good afternoon,

My dataflow suddenly stopped working after 2 weeks of flowless updates.

This is the error message I get every time I want to change something in it:

•   ID activity: 45e84c64-98c5-4518-9792-cc1a133768c0
•   ID request: b8963094-60e7-536f-64a2-27a4e89a46c5
•   ID correletion: 77cf355a-9ec0-fbe0-cc7d-4d4a27a330bf
•   Code:500
•   Time Jan 15 2020 18:18:30 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
•   Version:13.0.11747.315
•
•   URI clusteru https://wabi-north-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net/

Comment: How is the data connected to your report? Is it imported from a SQL server?

Comment: If it's a refresh failure we are talking about here, check out the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-troubleshooting-refresh-scenarios

Comment: Yes, SQL is source for dataflow.